# How to update value of one field for only particular count of second field?

Tags: mysql

Table has two fields `quantity` and`flag`.

suppose for example `quantity=3` and `flag=0` at initial state. When user needs to update `flag=1` for only `quantity=2` and `flag=2` for `quantity=1`.

How can I do that? **Is there anyway without creating a separate row for each `quantity=1`?**

Comment: I find this question confusing.  Do you mean when user updates flag=1 you want to set quantity to 2, and when user updates flag=2 you want to set quantity to 1?

Comment: @Tin Tran Yes I mean that

Comment: you can use trigger, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TRIGGER set_quantity BEFORE UPDATE ON Test
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
    IF NEW.flag = 1 THEN 
      SET NEW.quantity = 2;
    END IF;
    IF NEW.flag = 2 THEN 
      SET NEW.quantity = 1;
    END IF;
END/
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5b9bf4/1)